# UILabel disappearing in UIButton subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I've created a subclass of UIButton, inserted an animated view on touch and altered the positioning of my UIImage and UILabel via layoutSubviews. Now when I create six of these subclassed UIButtons in storyboard and run the App on my device I get the following:

[image: Missing UILabels]

It seems to work fine with 4 UIButtons but five and above always seems to effect my UILabels. Why do the right hand side UIButton's have their UILabels missing?

I'm thinking there is something odd occurring in layoutSubviews but I can't see it. The code for the method is below:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {

[super layoutSubviews];

CGRect imageFrame = self.imageView.frame;
imageFrame = CGRectMake(truncf((self.bounds.size.width - imageFrame.size.width) / 2), 40.0f, imageFrame.size.width, imageFrame.size.height);
self.imageView.frame = imageFrame;


CGRect labelFrame = self.titleLabel.frame;
labelFrame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.bounds.size.height - labelFrame.size.height - 10.0f, self.frame.size.width, labelFrame.size.height);
self.titleLabel.frame = labelFrame;
self.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

}

Any idea's?

Comment: If you inspect the frame of the label on the right side buttons, what are the values? Either the label is incorrectly sized or incorrectly positioned. Looking at the frame will tell you which problem you should be attacking.

Comment: have you checked what frames are you setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found out what the issue was. I was centring the alignment of my UIButton subviews  in the storyboard but still trying to set it's frame via layoutSubviews. This means it was altering the UILabel from its origin at the centre of the frame which pushes it to the right of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I would use auto layout to position the extra label within the button when I add it to the button. You should be able to specify horizontal centering, pin the label to the bottom of the button, and specify a minimum border to the leading and trailing edges.

If you use auto layout you won't need to modify the layoutSubviews. You can just let auto layout do all the math.

The visual format language would be something like:

```
"V:[label]-(5)-|"
"H:|-(>=5)-[label]-(>=5)-|"
```

The height of the label will be calculated by the contents intrinsic size. You would add those constraints to the UIButton class to which you've attached the label.